# wiring of occupancy switch in 3-way situation (odd-looking instructions)

Tags: electrical, lighting, multiway-switch

I'm looking to replace one of the two switches (wired in a standard 3-way configuration) which control an overhead light in a utility room, with an occupancy sensor switch.  The room is small enough that the one sensor should provide adequate coverage.

I've purchased an Eaton Model #OS306U, and the wiring instructions look most peculiar to me.  The switch has 3 wires, black, red, and blue (plus ground); I'd expect one of the wires to be the "common", and the switch makes a connection between common and either the red or the blue wire, much like a standard mechanical 3-way switch.   But it's not wired like that at all.   Here is an image from the instructions, for my scenario:

[image]

Neutral is wired as normal.  The occupancy sensor turns the light on or off by making or breaking the connection between its black and red wires (and the black, being connected to hot, probably powers the logic as well).  Meanwhile, the blue wire goes back to the other mechanical switch; this switch either leaves the blue wire open, or shorts it to ground.  Apparently the mechanical switch needn't even be a 3-way switch, a single-pole one would be fine (despite the labeling in the drawing).

I can't quite figure out what's going on.

Comment: But if you think about it, you wouldn't want things wired as a normal 3-way.   Suppose you walk into the room and turn the light on with the mechanical switch; then once the sensor sees you, it turns the light off.

Comment: I actually laughed out loud.  So true!

Comment: At my post, or my comment ?   (Just trying to make you laugh again).

Comment: "sensor sees you and turns the light off"...  I see so many attempts to combine different devices with little thought to how they'll interact, and that just sums it up!

Comment: Really though, occupancy sensors don't turn off because of sensing motion; they turn off because of not sensing motion for a specified length of time.

Comment: This question describes a switch that is meant to be wired in a similar manner, though none of the discussion addresses my question:  https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/136508/modifying-strange-3-way-switch-wiring

Comment: I open up my two switch boxes, and it turns out that a switch leg is used.    So one box has the 14/2 switch leg coming in, and a 14/3 cable going to the other box.   So I've gotta put the sensor in the 1st box.   And it's fortunate it doesn't require neutral.

Comment: So I wired it up: Black wire to switch-leg line, red to switch-leg load, green to ground, blue floating.    Nada: the light is just permanently on, button on the switch does nothing, grounding the blue wire does nothing.   Thinking I should just exchange for a single-pole one (from another mfg'er I've used and product works well); room is only 10x11ft, so single motion sensor should work fine.

Comment: Is your ground reliable and genuine?

Comment: Pretty sure ground is reliable & genuine.  What's best way to verify ?

Comment: Temporarily misconnect a receptacle with hot on the brass screws and **ground** on the silver.  If the receptacle can light a lamp, or trip a GFCI, the ground is good.

Comment: I'll try a lamp then (doesn't the GFCI just require it to sink a tiny amount of current that even a poor connection could handle ?).

Comment: Good point, fair chance a GFCI trip would be inconclusive.

Comment: So I connected a floor lamp to hot and ground with jumper clips.   Lights up fine.   Current is about 1/4 amp (had a CFL in it).   No noticeable difference in measured voltage with the lamp turned on or off (123.0 on Fluke DVM).   Looks like a solid ground and an utterly faulty sensor switch.  I exchanged it for a single-pole Lutron I've used in my shipping container that works like a champ; this room is 10x11ft so I think I'll be fine with the occupancy sensor and no second switching location.

Answer (score 2):

Yup, I agree with your read. That is exactly what's going on.

I am fairly impressed that UL *even allowed* this... I seem to recall seeing a bulletin from  NFPA  to the effect of "alright UL, it's time to stop approving things that use ground for more than ground".  Although it may be still allowed since it is surely a millivolt current.

Regardless, it's rather ingenious.  It liberates *two* wires completely, so for instance if the other switch is a remote spur, you can now use black and white for onward power.

Still won't let the put the sensor at the remote spur, that would require 4 wires (line, load, neutral and sense) plus ground.

Comment: I still don't understand exactly what's going on.  Flipping the mechanical switch changes the blue wire from "open" to "shorted to ground", or vice versa.   So if the light is off, flipping the mechanical switch turns it on, and the sensor goes into its "wait for no motion sensed for specified period of time" state.   If the light is on,  flipping the mechanical switch turns it off; so the sensor needs to ignore sensed motion for some time after that (otherwise we have the amusing situation I meant to describe in my 1st comment on OP).

Comment: So there's a kind of state machine in the smart switch, that knows when the blue wire's connectivity has changed, in either direction.

Comment: Haven't installed it yet.   Trying to understand theory of operation; that was meant to be my original question.

Comment: @RustyShackleford I am not sure how the logic of physical switch *and* motion sensor would work.  The reason I found your comment so funny is that people often want to stick together seemingly unrelated or contradictory control methods, and expect the amalgam to just "do what makes sense". When wires can't know that.  At least here, it's a single engineered product, so it ought to be reasonable.

Comment: I'm not even sure what "makes sense" in the scenario in my OP (specifically that wiring diagram).   Specifically, if the light is on, and I flip the mechanical switch to turn the light off, does the sensor ignore any motion for awhile ?  If not, and the mechanical switch is within "view" of the sensor (which would often, but not always, be the case), the light just comes back on.   If it ignores motion, for how long does it do so ?

Comment: @jsotola makes a good point though.  I should just shut up and install the thing and see what happens.

Comment: the device has no mechanical switches that turn power on/off directly .... the power is controlled electronically ... the switches and the motion sensor only provide low voltage signals to the controller  ...... i doubt that the controller is programmed to turn off the light when it gets a signal from the motion detector

Comment: @RustyShackleford I would bet the engineers thought seriously about UX and chose that which would be least likely to cause WTF returns from customers.  At least, if the device has a manual button, I would expect the remote switch to do the same thing as the button.

Comment: Good point: the FSM in the thing probably treats the mechanical switch and the button the same way.   So imagine a single-pole occupancy sensor switch: light is on, you turn it off with button on switch, at what point does sensor decide it's seen motion and it's time to turn the light back on ?

Comment: @RustyShackleford After much observation and contemplation of this question over the years, I conclude the likeliest answer is 42.

Comment: I'm thinking more like 47.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are getting confused by previous experiences with 3-way switches.

The OS306U is an electronic device, much like a light dimmer.

It has a controller that has several inputs, and the output of the controller causes the HOT (black) to be connected to OUTPUT (red); this turns on the light

The controller accepts inputs from three sources.

1. the push button on the OS306U
2. the motion sensor on the OS306U
3. an external switch

All three of these inputs probably connect the associated input pin to ground (same as the remote switch).

The controller is programmed to operate the output in a specific way, dependent on the state of the inputs.

Comment: Yep.   There's a finite-state machine (FSM) in the controller.    Hopefully it'll do what I want it too.